# Get values to time span type using TimePicker and razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, timepicker, timespan

I have a model that contains attribute of type `TimeSpan`:

```
public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
```

I want the user to enter values using a form to get the time span. I'm using timepicker lib and razor `@Html.EditorFor`.

The problem is that the attribute `Time` always gets the default values. I searched for this problem and some people talked about changing the time format but I didn't know how to do it

The html looks like this

```
  @Html.EditorFor(b => b.Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "time", @class = "form-control timepicker", @required = "" } })
```

when running the input looks like this:

[html timepicker lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKzQD.png)

How can I use the timepicker and razor in a simple way to get values for time span?

Comment: what time picker library are you using? please include relevant code for view and controller

Comment: I am not really sure .. i think it is the JQ timepicker